# It's possible to use django mysql model array field

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

In my case I need design my model in array of fields expected.

```
{field 1: string, field 2: [""], field 3: [""] }
```

So far I designed my model like following:

```
class Collaborator(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null = True, )

class Responsibility(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null = True, )


class Class1(models.Model):
    field 1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null = True, )
    field 2 = models.ManyToManyField(Responsibility, related_name='res_cards', blank=True,null=True )
    field 3 = models.ManyToManyField(Collaborator, related_name='col_cards', blank=True, null=True )
```

So I am expecting for to get all fields in an array rather than define new model

Comment: Please don't use spaces in variable names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using SQLite as your database, there is no alternative for `ManyToManyField`.

However, if you are using (or if you switch to) PostgreSQL as your database, you'll be able to use [`ArrayField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield).

You can use it like this:

```
field_1 = ArrayField(
            models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
          )
```

P.S. I assume you aren't really going to name your fields `field 1` etc., but if you do, don't use spaces, use underscores instead, so `field_1`, etc.

There is lots of information on how to use Postgres instead of SQLite, for instance [this link](https://medium.com/@aaditya.chhabra/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-django-272d59d28fa5) would be a good start.

However, in most cases I would still recommend using a ManyToManyField, because it'll enable you to easily query on shared relationships between two objects, and prevent duplicate data as well.

Comment: i'm using mysql as my database

Comment: In that case, you can use [django-my-sql, which supports a ListField](https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/list_fields.html#list-fields)

Comment: i already tried that there is no change i saw in my admin ui , it 's showing as text field

Comment: When I look at the docs it looks like you'll need to input your values in that textfield, separated by commas: `name1,name2,name3`